# How to evaluate all LogicalDisk instances in a machine excluding mapped network drives?

Tags: c#, .net-core, wmi, mapped-drive

I am writing a method to get the physical hardware serial number of the operating system drive. I am using the call

```
ManagementClass("Win32_LogicalDisk").GetInstances()
```

to get all drive instances in my machine. I am only interested in local, physically attached drives, specifically `C:`, however disconnected network drives are massively slowing the call down (up to a minute or two waiting on drives to fail to resolve).

In completeness, the method is scanning all `LogicalDisk` instances, correlating `C:` firstly using the `LogicalDiskToPartition` mapper, and secondly the `DiskDriveToDiskParition` mapper, to find the `DiskDrive` hosting the operating system<sup>1</sup>. Finally having the system's disk drive, I am gathering the `SerialNumber` of the disk (the ultimate objective of the method).

The method works perfectly in Windows however it is laborious if I can't eliminate network drives. I would welcome suggestions of faster ways of achieving my end goal, as well as how to make the method operating system agnostic (iOS, Linux, Android etc.)

<sup><sup>1</sup> If the operating system is not on `C:` then I would also welcome knowing how to generally identify the 'system' drive.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to find out where Windows is installed is simply to use the Special folder `System`

```
var systemPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System);    
Console.WriteLine($"System Path  = {systemPath }");
```

This will output something like:

> System Path = C:\WINDOWS\system32

So you can retrieve the disk from the first letter

You can also do this to retrieve drive information.
I believe it works on Windows & Linux, although I haven't tried it.

```
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)            
    Console.WriteLine($"Name = {d.Name}; Type = {d.DriveType} format = {d.DriveFormat} Label = {d.VolumeLabel} Root = {d.RootDirectory} IsReady = {d.IsReady}");
```

Comment: Good thought on the system path, I suppose in all other operating systems the root path is just `/`. The `DriveInfo` stuff is good but uses some other system, and doesn't produce a device 'Path' compatible with the remaining WMI calls.